# Trim Array value from specific char to specific char

Tags: javascript, angular

How to get specific value from array?
i.e.

```
"Names": [      
    "Name[name]",
    "Result[Type]",
    "Validation[Option]",
    "Status[Pointer]"
]
```

Output must be:

```
"Names": [        
    "name",
    "Type",
    "Option",
    "Pointer"
]
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

  Names = [
    "Name[name]",
    "Result[Type]",
    "Validation[Option]",
    "Status[Pointer]"
  ]


  constructor() {
    var modifiedNames = this.Names.map(x => x.split('[').pop().split(']')[0])
    console.log(modifiedNames)
  }
}
```

See [Stackbiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5vrqu)

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [
 "Name[name]",
 "Result[Type]",
 "Validation[Option]",
 "Status[Pointer]"
];

const newArray = array.map(e => /^\w+\[(\w+)\]$/.exec(e)[1]);

// ["name", "Type", "Option", "Pointer"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method and based on the start and end bracket grab the subtring. To iterate on every element of array use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, it creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
const arr =  [      
        "Name[name]",
        "Result[Type]",
        "Validation[Option]",
        "Status[Pointer]"
    ]

    let result = arr.map((a)=>{ return a.substring(a.indexOf("[") + 1 , a.indexOf("]")) });
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through array and using following regex to get the desired output.

```
const array = [
  "Name[name]",
  "Result[Type]",
  "Validation[Option]",
  "Status[Pointer]"
];
var regexTest = new RegExp(/\[([^\]]+)\]/);
var newArray = array.map(e => regexTest.exec(e)[1]);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wp6evs5o/) link

Answer (score 0):

substring and indexOf in action:

```
let newArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){  
    var s = array[i];
    var n = s.indexOf('[');
    s = s.substring(n+1, s.length-1);
    newArray.push(s);
}
```

OR

```
let newArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){  
    newArray.push(array[i].substring(array[i].indexOf('[')+1, array[i].length-1));
}
```